# populate radio button value after submit

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I try to implement the follwing code:

```
    <?php
    $yesno1="";
    $yesno2="";
    $option1="";
    $option2="";
    $option3="";
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      $yesno1=$_POST['yesno1'];
      $yesno2=$_POST['yesno2'];
      $option1=$_POST['option1'];
      $option2=$_POST['option2'];
      $option3=$_POST['option3'];
     } 
    ?>    
   <form method="POST" name="contact_form"
  action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
 <input type="radio" name="yesno1" value="yes" style="outline:0;"/>Yes
 <input type="radio" name="yesno1" value="no" style="outline:0;"/>No
 <input type="radio" name="yesno2" value="yes" style="outline:0;"/>Yes
 <input type="radio" name="yesno2" value="no" style="outline:0;"/>No
 <input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="Milk"> Milk<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="Butter" checked> Butter<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="option3" value="Cheese"> Cheese<br>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" name='submit'>
 </form>
```

Once I click submit button, normally the value I seleted in radio and marked in the checkbox are gone, so how can I keep the value even after the click the submit button or refrsh the page using php, javascript is fine as well, would be better if any one can help me with it on both php and javascript since I am not very good on both of them, thanks for kind help:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example below

```
<input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="Milk" <?php echo ($_POST['option1'] == 'Milk' ? 'checked' : '') ?>> Milk<br>
```

Comment: but be sure to sanitize the input or someone will send you `" onclick=location.replace('http://hackersite.com')` to store in your database

Answer (score 1):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/input):

> The input (`<input>`) element is used to create interactive controls for
>   web-based forms.
>
> **Attributes**
>
> *type*
>
> [...]
>
> `radio`: A radio button. You must use the `value` attribute to define the
>   value submitted by this item. **Use the `checked` attribute to indicate
>   whether this item is selected by default.** Radio buttons that have the
>   same value for the `name` attribute are in the same "radio button
>   group"; only one radio button in a group can be selected at one time.

This is a basic HTML question. Learn to walk before you run ;-)